# Ubuntu - no audio after upgrade to 22.04.1

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, webcam

My internal speaker, headphones, and webcam do not work after upgrading from 20.04. Everything worked correctly before upgrading.

I suspect that the speaker/headphone issue is caused by missing the snd-hda-intel kernel module. Not only is the module not running, I cannot find any evidence that it even exists on the computer.

The webcam that isn't working is a Logitech webcam.

How should I proceed to try to fix this? I cannot figure out any apt packages that might install snd-hda-intel.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling pulseaudio?

Comment: Run `modinfo snd-hda-intel` and see if the module is there.

Comment: It ended up being that the computer wasn't using the default kernel for 20.04.  When I did the upgrade it added a grub entry for 5.15, but the default was still 5.13.  Once I changed to boot with the 5.15 kernel everything started working.